# UISegmentedControl (with images) in UITableViewCell (AutoLayout) always 29 points high

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout, uisegmentedcontrol

Standard `Tableview` app. Autolayout. Each (cell) class has its own .xib file, no storyboard.

I have a segmented control in a `tableview` cell filling it (almost) completely, with all 4 edges bound with 6 points space to its container (=content view of the `tableViewCell`). The segments are made from images, not text.

I would expect when I call `-[setImage: forSegmentAtIndex:]` that the control changes its intrinsic content size to make enough space for the segment images - especially the view height.
I did set it's Content Hugging Priority to 251 (and the cell's hugging priority stays at default 250), so when I use narrow images the segmented control height should shrink (and the cell content view height also). And when I use larger images the segmented control height should grow...
I compute the correct height by measuring an invisible reference cell (dequeued myself in `-[viewDidLoad]` and kept in a `viewController` property),
asking Autolayout for  `-[systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize]` for the reference cell's contentView. This works fine, I get different sizes to return in `-[tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath]` for different images. So `AutoLayout` computes the height to be used correctly.

But the real (visible) cell of the `tableView` doesn't change the height of the segmented control. It always stays at 29 points (which is the standard height for a segmented control with text labels and not images), no matter what `cellHeight` being used and what images set.

I tried to add another `NSLayoutConstraint` to the segmented control, where I just set it's height:

```
heightConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self
                                                   attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                   relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationGreaterThanOrEqual
                                                 toItem:nil
                                                   attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                                                 multiplier:1
                                               constant:newHeight];
```

and add that (once) to the segmented control. I got "Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints" when I tried `NSLayoutRelationEqual`, that's why I used `NSLayoutRelationGreaterThanOrEqual`. (Probably computed the `newHeight` value wrong).
But it still doesn't work - 29 points and garbled images in the segments...

What am I doing wrong? Or is this an iOS bug with `UISegmentedControl` and `AutoLayout`?
Of course I could just revert to manual layout and just set the frame of the segmented control - but I'd like to use `AutoLayout`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:

implement

```
-(CGSize)intrinsicContentSize
{
     CGSize          size = CGSizeMake(288, 68);

     return size;
}
```

on my segmentedControl subclass. Well, of course compute the height based on the actual image height instead of using 68, but this works...